How to Refresh List in SwiftUI with @Observable Model
I am trying to understand why my row views don't refresh when I am repopulating the array holding them.
As a sample, I have the following views.
//main content view which generates a list full of PersonRow
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var org : Organization = .shared
  
  var body: some View {
    List(org.people) {
      PersonRow(person: $0)
    }
    .padding()
    
    Button(action: {
      org.createPeople()
    }) {
      Text("Create People")
    }
  }
}

//Row representing each person.
struct PersonRow : View {
  @State var person : Person //observable
  
  var body: some View {
    let color : Color = person.isActive ? .blue : .red
    HStack {
      
    Text(person.name)
      .foregroundStyle(color)
      
      Spacer()
      
      Button(action: {
        person.isActive.toggle()
      }) {
        Text(person.isActive ? "Active" : "Inactive")
      }
    }
    .padding()
  }
}

@Observable class Person : Identifiable, Equatable {
  static func == (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool { lhs.id == rhs.id }
  
  var id : String = ""
  var name: String = "John Doe"
  var isActive: Bool = true
}

@Observable class Organization {
  
  static let shared = Organization()
  
  private init() { createPeople() }
  
  var people: [Person] = []
  
  func createPeople() {
    people.removeAll()
    
    for i in 0..<10 {
      let p = Person()
      p.id = "\(i)"
      p.name = "John Doe \(i)"
      people.append(p)
    }
    
    print("Created people")
  }
}

On each row, when clicking active vs inactive it toggles as expected and the view updates as expected.
However, when I click "Create People" in the ContentView, I repopulate the entire Organization array with a new set of Person, but the list doesn't refresh. This is where I am having an issue. Shouldn't the list refresh since I am observing Oragnization and the array was updated? Can someone explain what it is I am doing incorrectly?

State makes a deep copy of Observable you should use @Bindable instead. Also note that State should always be private. That Equatable implementation also tells SwiftUI to only refresh when the id changes, you have to include all properties for Equatable

@loremipsum Thank you! I've been working on this for days and somehow missed any reference to @Bindable. Is there any way to do this while keeping Equatable and relying only on the ID for it? I have reason for this particular setup.

No, Equatable is used by SwiftUI to know if something has changed. If only the id is taken into consideration then only a change in id will trigger a change.

Thank you! I would mark your answer as correct but no way to do that as a comment. Feel free to put an answer up anytime.

State makes a deep copy of Observable you should use @Bindable instead. Also note that State should always be private.
That Equatable implementation also tells SwiftUI to only refresh when the id changes, you have to include all properties for Equatable.

This answer explains what I am doing wrong. Followup question. Is there a way for me to tell the List itself to recreate all its rows? I know there's nothing like reloadData but some trick to force this update?

@MAH You could give the list an “id” and change the “id”. This solution is terrible in terms of efficiency it will recreate everything.

Got it. Agree not a great approach. I will try to work around Equatable stuff. Time to restructure. Thanks again for your help.

@MAH I just added an answer that may offer some insight into everything. You don't have to give the List an id, as it will automatically refresh itself when data changes. So maybe give that a read before you restructure everything.

As pointed out by @loremipsum in the comments, given the Equatable protocol, the id value is essential.
The issue is your createPeople() function recreates the same people - with the same name and same ID (from 0 to 10). So, technically there is no change  to show.
If you randomize the id, or if the actual data will contain different ids, it should work fine:
func createPeople() {
        people.removeAll()
        
        for i in 0..<10 {
            let p = Person()
            p.id = "\(UUID())" // <-- HERE, randomize id
            p.name = "John Doe \( p.id.suffix(4) )" // <-- HERE, show the last 4 characters of the UUID as part of the name
            people.append(p)
        }
        
        print("Created people")
    }

However, note that if any of the new IDs do NOT change, the person status will be maintained/remembered. See below, given a more limited randomization, as you click to disable some people and create new ones, if any of the new ones have the same id, the status will not be reset:
func createPeople() {
        people.removeAll()
            
        for i in 0..<10 {
            let p = Person()
            p.id = "\(Int.random(in: 0..<50))" // <-- HERE, randomize id
            p.name = "John Doe \(p.id)" // <-- HERE, show the id as part of the name
            people.append(p)
        }
        
        print("Created people")
    }

As a side note, State should work fine here. So should Bindable. So should just let or var. Thus, instead of @State private var org : Organization = .shared, you could have:
//@State private var org : Organization = .shared
@Bindable var org : Organization = .shared

or:
//@State private var org : Organization = .shared
let org : Organization = .shared

... and it would still work since you're using @Observable.
You could even use @Bindable or let in the body:
struct ContentView: View {

    //@State private var org : Organization = .shared

    var body: some View {
        
        @Bindable var org = Organization.shared // <-- HERE, this will also work
        //let org = Organization.shared // <-- or this (uncomment to use and comment out the @Bindable line above

        List(org.people) {

or even:
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        
        let people = Organization.shared.people // <-- HERE, this will also work

        List(people) {
    

Whether you use one or another would depend mostly on how you get or use the data. In this case, you're getting it directly from the class, but you could pass it to subviews as a binding or use it in the body for unwrapping if dealing with optionals.
Example 1 - Initialized in root view as State and passed to subview, which receives a Binding to State:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var org : Organization = .shared
    
    var body: some View {
        
        PersonList(organization: $org) // <-- Here, passing State as a binding
        
        Button(action: {
            org.createPeople()
        }) {
            Text("Create People")
        }
    }
}

struct PersonList: View {
    
    @Binding var organization: Organization // <-- Here, receiving binding from parent
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List(organization.people) {
            PersonRow(person: $0)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


Example 2 - Initialized in root view as State and passed to subview via environment (notice the lack of parameters needed).
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var org : Organization = .shared
    
    var body: some View {
        
        PersonList() // <-- Here, notice no parameters
            .environment(org)
        
        Button(action: {
            Organization.shared.createPeople() // <--
        }) {
            Text("Create People")
        }
    }
}

struct PersonList: View {
    
    @Environment(Organization.self) private var org // <-- Here, receiving environment from parent
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List(org.people) {
            PersonRow(person: $0)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


However, if passed as environment, rather than State, you don't have a binding. And if you do need one, this is where Bindable comes in handy. Consider the following, where I added a var isActive: Bool = true to Organization class:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var org : Organization = .shared
    
    var body: some View {
        
        PersonList() // <-- Here, notice no parameters
            .environment(org)

        
        Button(action: {
            org.createPeople()
        }) {
            Text("Create People")
        }
    }
}

struct PersonList: View {
    
    @Environment(Organization.self) private var org // <-- Here, receiving environment from parent
    
    var body: some View {
        
        @Bindable var organization = org // <-- HERE, get a binding to an observable object (a bindable object)
        
        Toggle(isOn: $organization.isActive, label: { // <-- Here, using Binding format to directly change the status
            Text("Status: \( org.isActive ? "Active" : "Inactive")")
        })
        .fixedSize()

        List(org.people) {
            PersonRow(person: $0)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


In the end, given the use of a Class here, it matters little which one you use, because everything is passed by reference. If you used other models, like structs or states that load from user defaults, etc., then understanding the differences will be essential.
Hope this helps.

Thank you. This is excellent information. I have to play around with it a bit to really grasp everything. I am used to AppKit. This is a shift in thinking.

It's now just let for @Observable class model objects (we used to need @ObservedObject var), e.g.
struct ContentView: View {
    let org = Organization.shared // singleton, usually called Store that loads/saves models

And
struct PersonRow : View {
    let person: Person // @Observable owned by the store

@State is for view data values or structs owned by a View not for models.
See 9:40 in this video for the distinction between view data and model data.
https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10040?time=580

But State is designed for transient UI state that is local to a view. In this section, I want to move your attention to designing your model and explain all the tools that SwiftUI provides to you.
Typically, in your app, you store and process data by using a data model that is separate from its UI.
This is when you reach a critical point where you need to manage the life cycle of your data, including persisting and syncing it, handle side-effects, and, more generally, integrate it with existing components. This is when you should use ObservableObject. First, let's take a look at how ObservableObject is defined.

